# Can an IME (soft keyboard) get the name of the app using it?

Tags: android

Can an IME get the name of the app using it? (assuming it has the right permissions)

Thanks in advance,
Barry

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answering my own question again! :)

The `EditorInfo` passed to `InputMethodService.onStartInput()` and `onStartInputView()` contains the member `EditorInfo.packageName` which contains the name of the calling app's package.

Answer (score 1):

Try getCurrentInputEditorInfo().packageName

In add to your question and answer can you know how get current name Activity and name of field?